# Flutter: How. to get a centered section title bar with button on right

Tags: flutter

I've discovered that Flutter has a certain way of taking something that look easy and driving you nuts trying to figure it out. In my case I need a full width section header within a `Column`. The section needs to have a white background, a centered text title and a button on the right. Something like this:

[image: Screen shot]

Then I ran into some problems:

- How do I center the text and right align the button?
- How do I size the container to the text. and icon, but not to the size of the button as it makes the area too big?

Here's. what I have currently:

```
    return Container(
      color: theme.cardColor,
      // constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(FormFieldFactory.sidePadding.left),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Text(
              localisations.today,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: theme.textTheme.subtitle1,
            ),
          ),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded), onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

The problem with it is that the `IconButton` is making the container too tall and it's on the left. I tried wrapping an `OverflowBox` around the icon so it could overflow and let the text dictate the size, but all I got was a massive log of errors about widgets with no size.

So what am I missing? I feel like this should be in the 'not that hard' basket but I've been fiddling with it for hours trying to figure out it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Shubhamhackz I re-appraised the code and what I was doing. I realised that I had started with the text label first and then tried to add the button. As the button was bigger in height I then went down the road of trying to fit it and overflow it so that it was centered vertically with the text.

What I should have done was recognise that the button would take more space, switched my thinking around and centered the text with it whilst shrinking the top and bottom padding.

Ultimately I ended up with this:

```dart
    return Container(
      color: theme.cardColor,
      padding: FormFieldFactory.sidePadding,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            localisations.today,
            style: theme.textTheme.subtitle1,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded), onPressed: () {}),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

**What I understood from your question is that you want to make something like the image you shown. Here's how you can do :**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: width,
          height: height * 0.08,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  'Title',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline,
                    size: 28,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. I ended up with something slightly different and realised I'd been chasing a less than suitable approach.